# Why are auxiliary verbs omitted in informal English?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, ellipsis

In informal English i see people to say and text

1: you married?

2: he told to not come

3: you done?

4: the paragraph written in informal English

So on

How the sentences make sense without any help of auxiliary verb?

It's OK to write the way informally?

Comment: _He told to not come_ is not something I would expect to hear from any native English speaker. We simply don't omit the object of _tell_, even in informal speech, and even when it is obvious. Also _He told me not to come_ is much more common than _He told me to not come_ in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this tends to be more common in informal English and all this makes perfect sense. Verbs (it doesn't have to be just auxiliary verbs) that come at the beginning of a sentence are often left out in spoken English (or in situations where spoken English is being imitated such as chatting over an instant messaging app) for the sake of brevity. One reason this is possible is because from the context it's still quite clear what you are saying (no essential information is lost, in other words):

> **(Are)** you married?
>
> **(Are)** you done?

In the last example (*the paragraph written in informal English*), *written* is something called a past participle. When past participles are used like that, you can always paraphrase the sentence by inserting *that is* or *that are* between the noun and the past participle:

> the paragraph **that is** written in informal English

This is normal for past participles. It has nothing to do with the level of formality you're speaking with.

I'm not sure about example #2. Where is there supposed to be an auxiliary verb that has been left out of the sentence?

Comment: i have seen many places, in formal writing as well that [that is] is omitted to make clause and phrases shorten, as like The board [that/which is] docked at the Port

Comment: And I'm talking about informal writing

Comment: "written is something called a past participle", i think your answer require [that is] in between something and called just like "written is something [that is] called a past participle"

Comment: Yes, you can do that, but that's not a requirement: **"written" is something that is called** and **"written" is something called** are absolutely equivalent phrasings. The latter one is just a shorter way to say it.

Comment: Thank you, that means "the paragraph written in informal English" is also acceptable?

Comment: Absolutely acceptable. Moreover, a lot more common.

Comment: But _the paragraph written in informal English_ (a noun phrase, not a sentence) is not restricted to informal English. Omitting a verb or auxiliary in a main clause is informal; condensing a relative clause by "whiz deletion" (i.e removing that/which/who is/are/was/were") is common in all registers.

Comment: Thank you Colin Fine, "It is the most common functional style of speech, the idiom normally employed in conversation and other informal contexts"

I think, there should be an auxiliary in between "normally" and "employed" like (normally is employed) in the sentence/ phrase inside quotation as it's not a relative clause. Am i right? I appreciate your reply